# Use of internal libraries in an external listener

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently implementing a payment system that requires an ok.php and ko.php URL for payment confirmation. When receiving confirmation in ok.php, i want to first check the data matches with mine through the library (There's a method for that), and then send an email from a custom mailer class. 
The problem is that those libraries are protected against direct access thorough:

`<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`

As the ok.php is accessed by the payment processor, it cannot be loaded through CodeIgniter and thus it doesn't have 'BASEPATH' defined and can't access those libraries.

I found [this](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/101620/#716311) post regarding the access to the CodeIgniter superobject, but I am concerned about the security of that, and other possible repercussions of not loading in the "intended" way.

Which would be the correct way to create a listener URL and access CodeIgniter functions?